# how to make a textbox non clickable using html

Tags: html, textbox, safari

I want to make textarea non-editable and non-clickable using html.
I have given the "readonly=true" for the tags; however, it is still clickable but non-editable. The readonly textarea are getting selected in Safari browser. Please help. I do not want the text area and text box to get selected.
Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Using `readonly` attribute on element means that the element is not editable, however the value of field gets submitted when the form is submitted.

While `disabled` element is not editable as `readonly` but its value doesn't get submitted on form submission.

so, if you want to submit the value of the field, use:

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" readonly />
```

else

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" disabled="disabled" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `disabled="disabled"`. This will disable textbox / textarea, so it won't be selected. Also, the value won't be submitted on form submission.

For textbox :

```
<input type="text" name="textbox1" disabled="disabled" />
```

For textarea :

```
<textarea name="textarea1" disabled="disabled" /></textarea>
```

In HTML5, only `disabled` attribute will also work. The value is not compulsory. However, for XHTML Strict you will need `key & value` pair.

Comment: <td><html:textarea property="eyfXSmsPleTaPleTx" rows="5" cols="50"  style="width:100%;" styleClass="formbox" readonly="true" disabled="disabled" ></html:textarea>

This is the code I am using.

Comment: double clicking still allows for the selection of text

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

Comment: i think it should be textarea not textbox. also for textbox you will need input tag.

Comment: I am really sorry. Yes the problem is with the textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Try this i hope it works,

```
<input type="text" name="country" value="anytext" readonly>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with

```
disabled="disabled"
```